# How to create a list after a groupby function in python, after a certain condition on the column?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like below:

```
Number  Time Response 
0       3    6
1       5    0
2       33   4
3       15   6
4       12   2
```

I am performing a groupby based on the response, and getting a list of Time

```
df.groupby('Response')['Time'].apply(list)
```

I dont know how to set a condition where only 'Time' of response values '6' should be populated.

np.where didnot work.

Expected output:

```
The list of time for response 6: [3,15]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just refer to the particular grouped id in your list:

```py
>>> df.groupby("Response")["Time"].apply(list)[6]
[3, 15]
```